# Unable to find the SAML 2 binding used for this request.array

Tags: php, active-directory, saml, adfs

I m integrating simplesamlphp with adfs. Everything is working fine, but after Authentication from ADFS, while redirecting to my website, I am getting this error.

```
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 4 [c29af14b35] Unable to find the SAML 2 binding used for this request.array (#012)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 4 [c29af14b35] Request method: 'GET'array (#012)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 4 [c29af14b35] Content-Type: ''array (#012)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] SimpleSAML_Error_Error: ACSPARAMS
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] Backtrace:
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] 1 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:21 (require)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] 0 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:150 (N/A)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] Caused by: Exception: Unable to find the current binding.
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] Backtrace:
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] 2 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/vendor/simplesamlphp/saml2/src/SAML2/Binding.php:97 (SAML2_Binding::getCurrentBinding)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] 1 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php:16 (require)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] 0 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/www/module.php:150 (N/A)
Jul 15 21:42:04 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18035]: 3 [c29af14b35] Error report with id 952d6328 generated.
Jul 15 21:42:28 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18036]: 3 [31b86628bc] SimpleSAML_Error_Exception: Error 4096 - Argument 2 passed to sspmod_saml_SP_LogoutStore::addSession() must be of the type array, null given, called in /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php on line 190 and defined
Jul 15 21:42:28 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18036]: 3 [31b86628bc] Backtrace:
Jul 15 21:42:28 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18036]: 3 [31b86628bc] 3 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/www/_include.php:75 (SimpleSAML_error_handler)
Jul 15 21:42:28 QA-saml simplesamlphp[18036]: 3 [31b86628bc] 2 /data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/lib/SP/LogoutStore.php:159 (sspmod_saml_SP_LogoutStore::addSession)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have just received the same error.
It seems the be a bug in a simplesamlphp library.

Commenting the line out `sspmod_saml_SP_LogoutStore::addSession($sourceId, $nameId, $sessionIndex, $logoutExpire);` in `/data/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/modules/saml/www/sp/saml2-acs.php` will solve the problem.

Otherwise, it's better to update the library.
You can see the fix here: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/commit/c0721a6230748a54666a97f3b14f98398901a03d